# jQuery toggle list code redundancy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a list toggle code effecient.  I plan on making about 20 lists and copying pasting the code and changing the classes seems really inefficient.  I just can't figure out a way to make it work.

Here is what I have so far.  I would like to be able to toggle the main bullet's list upon clicking the main bullets.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".one").click(function() {
    $("ul.legislative.one").toggle('slow');
  });
  $(".two").click(function() {
    $("ul.legislative.two").toggle('slow');
  });
  $(".three").click(function() {
    $("ul.legislative.three").toggle('slow');
  });
  $(".four").click(function() {
    $("ul.legislative.four").toggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
ul.legislative {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="one">This is 1</li>
  <ul class="legislative one">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="two">This is 2</li>
  <ul class="legislative two">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="three">This is 3</li>
  <ul class="legislative three">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="four">This is 4</li>
  <ul class="legislative four">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/tqu7u2pn/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $(".one").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.legislative').toggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
ul.legislative {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="one">This is 1</li>
  <ul class="legislative">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="one">This is 2</li>
  <ul class="legislative">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="one">This is 3</li>
  <ul class="legislative">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="one">This is 4</li>
  <ul class="legislative">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I figured out how to do it with jQuery's next, but I would still like to see how other people do it because what if I wanted to call a list that was a different spot and not in the "next()" slot.

Comment: You can put a `data-rel` attribute in the LI, and put the ID of the related element in there. Then use `$('#' + $(this).data('rel')).toggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach with a bit of css class changes and also use correct semantics for ul li for valid html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="menu">This is 1</li>
  <li class="legislative">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">This is 2</li>
  <li class="legislative">
   <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">This is 3</li>
  <li class="legislative">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">This is 4</li>
  <li class="legislative">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $("ul.main-menu li").click(function(){
     $(this).next().toggle('slow');
  });    
 });
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
 .legislative {
   display:none; 
   list-style: none; 
   margin-top:-15px; 
  }
 </style>
```